# Java birt report deployment with tomcat server

Tags: java, report, birt

I am new to java birt report .

If i run a static file (test.rptdesign) it works fine but if i run the dynamic template 
it gives me the Database connection error
the error logs is:

[This is error log i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IttBq.png)

I tried a solution from [This given  Link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/501368/)

But not getting solved

**NOTE: It is running Fine in Eclipse environment But not running through CMD**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem. i solved it by just...
Try to put the Sqlite.jar in your tomcat inside web-app directory.

You can download the jar from here    [sqlit-jdbc jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqlitejdbc372jar.htm)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes I found directory but it need to put jar inside:
..\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\webapps\WebViewerExample\WEB-INF\lib

Thanks for your response.

Comment: yeah put it as per your app's need.